# Not able to return from cloud function

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fetch users from cloud function on the basis of certain logic but I am not able to capture the return statement.

Below is my Flutter Logic

```
try {
      HttpsCallable callable =
          FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('onGetUserOptions');

      final result = await callable.call({'uid': '6BgNSEpkYPKhdCUagtHm'});

      userOptions = result.data();
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
      log.e(error.code);
      log.e(error.details);
      log.e(error.message);
    } catch (error) {
      log.e(error.toString());
    }
```

Below is my clound function

```
export const onGetUserOptions = functions.https // }) //   enforceAppCheck: true, // .runWith({
  .onCall(async (data, context) => {
    
    return {
      code: 200,
      status: 'success',
      message: 'User options fetched successfully',
      //data: options.val(),
      data: 'This is the data',
    };
  });
```

I am getting below error

```
FirebaseFunctionsException ([firebase_functions/unknown] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 1 out of 2 underlying tasks failed

#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:22:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      QuestionController.getUserOptions (package:projectpurr3/controllers.dart/question_controller.dart:70:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _PollScreenState.fetchNames (package:projectpurr3/mainscreen/poll_screen.dart:112:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
)
```

The logic is function is working correctly till the end. Only I am not able to capture the response. Kindly guide.